# If formula with 3 different conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get 3 conditions by using `if-else` formula or any other relevant one.

I have 3 different dates `Starts date`, `End date` and `Grace period date` for an inventory.

I want "running" if today's date is greater than starts date but less than end date.

I want "Grace" if todays date is greater than end date but less than grace period

I want "Expired" if todays date is greater than grace period date.

I am using this formula but I am getting #value

```
IF(TODAY()>=E2<=F2,"Running",AND(IF(TODAY()>=F2<=G2,"Grace","Expired")))
```

Comment: Please, Can u describe the Column E2,F2 and G2?

Comment: e2 is start date, f2 is end date and g2 is grace period date.

Comment: grace period date (g2) is = end date (f2) + 30 days

Comment: Have you tried using the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formula tab to isolate where the error is? You may also try to break your formula down across several columns. `TODAY()>=E2<=F2` will throw an error; `TODAY()>=E2` should return either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @BhavnaSolanki if the answer given by Mike is helpful then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine conditions like that.  Instead of testing x>=y<=z, you need to use a logical `AND` and test both x>=y and y<=z.

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>=E2, TODAY()<=F2),"Running",IF(AND(TODAY()>=F2, TODAY()<=G2),"Grace","Expired"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I Spent almost 2 days, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Hi, same with above question,  if it is near to "expire" then can i get the highlight say before 5 days? is there any conditional formatting for that?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple if statements you should just use a lookup table instead

Put this in `A1:A4` (for example - these are your start date, near to expiry date, finish date and grace date)

```
01/05/2014
05/11/2014
10/11/2014
10/12/2014
```

And the following in `B1:B4`

```
Running
Near to expiry
Expired
Grace
```

Your formula would then be:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$4,MATCH(TODAY(),$A$1:$A$4,1),2)
```

Change TODAY() in the MATCH() formula as needed

Comment: I have three columns i.e in cell E - Starts date, cell F - End date, Cell G - Grace period date. i want highlight before 5 days in cell H (which containing "running","Grace", "Expired" ) when deal near to expire. Expired in my case would be " end date" + "Grace period date"

Comment: You need to look into conditional formatting if you want to hightlight one of the words "running", "grace" or "expired". You can define a formula for conditional formatting depending on your dates. Otherwise, just order B1:B4 in my solution to have "Near to expiry" at the right time